# Play audio file stored in google drive (remote URL) - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using AVPlayer to play audios which are stored in google drive. Problem is that as public link of files stored in google drive don't have extension mentioned, that's why AVPlayer doesn't play audio because cannot get its extension from URL. Following is code i'm using.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n6GeWY11Txvou5K-Tl7Ju39fQsWQTDvR/view?usp=sharing")

        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)

        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        player!.play()
```

For example, in case of following url

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n6GeWY11Txvou5K-Tl7Ju39fQsWQTDvR/view?usp=sharing

AVPlayer isn't playing it and showing it's duration to 0.

But when i play audio file like following

https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/BabyElephantWalk60.wav

it plays without any problem because of file extension available.

So, could someone please comment how to play audio when extension not available in remote URLs.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift won't play audio from link - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041441/swift-wont-play-audio-from-link-ios)

Comment: I faced the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Just got to modify the URL, Use this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1n6GeWY11Txvou5K-Tl7Ju39fQsWQTDvR
```

Here's what I did,

Sharing an audio file looks like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/view?usp=sharing
```

`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is the file ID. You can access the direct file by getting rid of everything after the ID and replacing `file/d/` with `uc?export=open&id=`

Keep in mind, if Google decide to change the way their file sharing works then this solution may break.

Comment: Hello, I try to play audio files from Goodle Drive too. I get track url like you write above: 'h_t_t_p_s://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXXXXXX' But AVPlayer doesn't play track from url. Url looks like this : 'h_t_t_p_s://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1sV8pTS3PiUKeU5VLGAC97Ql8nvnvXqfc"' ? If I open this url in browser - it plays