# How to play audio files from Google Drive (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, avplayer

In my project I use a Google Drive API. I get a list of the user's files and can save them to the device memory.
I also want to be able to play audio files directly from Google Drive, but I just can't do it. The AVPlayer doesn't want to play the audio file using the URL link, which I transfer to him. But if I paste this link into any browser, then the track is played.
Has anyone encountered this and knows how to fix the problem? I would be grateful for any help.
My code looks like this (it's a simplified version):

```
import AVKit

class MyVC: UIViewController {
...
var player: AVPlayer!
...
private func playTrack() {
   let url = URL(string: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXX" //where XXXXX is an item id
   let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
   player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
   player!.play()
   }
}
```

For example URL link which I transfer to the AVPlayer looks like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1JzuAhQ-7R01wLhtD8zEN_sC5nvFlt7wU
```

But if I paste it into the browser it automatically changes and looks like this:

```
https://doc-0g-1s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/anu2dlv0j1ugsoh1pb6b8qpkkt7k1j6k/hp3dnmru336i1cpkk4f5p4bstc83b30f/1602827400000/02426681720429398713/02426681720429398713/1JzuAhQ-7R01wLhtD8zEN_sC5nvFlt7wU?e=open&authuser=0&nonce=4dd9dhoo6he8g&user=02426681720429398713&hash=o87f0k3t4iv19ugae899urmcjd14ogiq
```

Maybe it's important.

Comment: so the provided URL has required any authentication of google session or without authentication, it will work?

Comment: Of course the authentication is successful, otherwise I wouldn't be able to get the file id. I wrote that the code in the example is simplified.

Comment: Yes you get that id after authentication but to access a specific URL you need to pass your token in it otherwise you can't access that directly and that is the problem I can see in your case.

Comment: But why it works in browser even I don't logged in Google?

Comment: for example, check your 2nd URL which is working fine why bcus you have an active session in your browser so it will take user session details and append it in your item url.

Comment: try to open in the private or incognito mode it will redirect to the login page.

Comment: No, I check it. Second URL doesn't work too

Comment: @CodeChanger As I understand it, I must somehow insert the token into the URL link? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You files should be shared by a direct link in Google Drive to play it so you can make it manually or using API e.g.:

[image]

And then use direct links in format: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXX.

Comment: Sorry, but I try to use link like this: _https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JzuAhQ-7R01wLhtD8zEN_sC5nvFlt7wU/view?usp=sharing I also try to follow this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55726883/play-audio-file-stored-in-google-drive-remote-url-swift but it doesn't help me too

Comment: You just should share access to your file first and then use links in format https://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXXX. I've tested with my google drive's files and it works OK.

Comment: As you can see, I'm also trying to use the same format for URL link. Apparently I have a problem with access to the file, can you explain in more detail what you mean "You just should share access to your file first"?

Comment: By default all you files have `Restricted` access so they are not accessible by links, if you  share your files by setting `Anyone with the link` they became accessible by direct, preview etc. links.

Comment: Sorry, where I must change it?

Comment: Tap context menu on you file in Google Dive and then 'Get Link' item or use API

Comment: I understood. This should be done by every user in their Google Drive. But how can I play user's music from Google Drive without their permission? I know apps which can do it. And I want too.

Comment: Think you should use oAuth etc. to ask user to grant access to his files.

Comment: I use OAuth 2.0 Client ID with my app. I think I already have full access. I can get list of user's files and I can download them...

Comment: I also checked my Scopes in the Google API console. I have selected all that are available without verification of the application